# pytest and flask: keep liver server alive for test class

Tags: python, flask, pytest

I'm trying to implement unit tests (with pytest) for my Flask app.

My app performs some I/O-intensive tasks that last several minutes at init, and I therefore would like to start one live server for my tests, and test all the end points on the same instance of the server.

Here is my conftest:

```
@pytest.fixture
def app():

    os.environ["FLASK_ENV"] = "development"
    os.environ["DATABASE_URI"] = os.path.join(
        ds.WORK_DIR, "tests", "fake_db.sqlite"
    )
    app = create_app()

    # http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.test_client
    app.testing = True

    return app
```

And here is the test class I'm trying to run:

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("live_server")
class TestLiveServer:
    def test_server_is_up_and_running(self):
        res = requests.get(url_for("index", _external=True))

        assert res.status_code == 200, "Index end point didn't return correct answer"
        assert "worksies" in res.text, "worksies not returned..."

    def test_proper_db(self):
        res = requests.get(url_for("all_products", _external=True))
```

The code above works, everything is loaded and tested perfectly, but it seems a new server is started for each of the `test_` method. At the very least, the I/O tasks are performed twice.

How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `scope=session` for your fixture. It will be executed only once per test session.

```
@pytest.fixture(scope=session)
def app():
    # your code here
```

I don't know what is `live_server` fixture, but suggest it maybe marked as session-scoped too.